# How can I get the image URL in a field?

Tags: views, 8

The image formatter has only one option: Image. I would like to get the URL, not the full markup, for a field output.

Do I need to make a custom formatter? Also, I don't see any way to rewrite the text using tokens to get the image URL.

Comment: There is a module image url formatter that only has a drupal 7 version.  Your only other option at the moment is to port that module over to D8.

Comment: It makes me feel dirty, but I'm just going to regex it out of the markup on the client side for now.

Comment: I will love to do this without the "Image URL Formatter."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When setting up your view, under the *advanced* section you can create a *relationship* for the image field.

After you added the relationship, you can then add a *File URI* field, select the created relationship and you are good to go.

Comment: I much prefer this method than installing yet another module for something that should be out-of-the-box functionality.

Answer (score 8):

This is the magic, without the "Image URL Formatter" module:

1. You have to add a relationship in your view to your image field (It's under Advanced)
2. Now you can add a 'File URI' field to your fields
3. In your views-view-fields.html.twig template (Or one of the appropriate alternatives for your specific view) add this:

`{{ file_url(fields.uri.content|striptags|trim) }}`

Answer (score 2):

Is the module "Image URL Formatter" maybe helpful for you?
https://www.drupal.org/node/1162614/release?api_version%5B%5D=7234

There is a second one:
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_raw_formatter

I never did a feature comparison to find out which is the better one ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the module [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)
2. Create a relationship in a View
3. Add *File URI* field, exclude it from display
4. Overwrite result, with the next twig code:

   {{ uri | image_style('thumbnail') }}

Where *uri* is the token of the *File URI* field and *thumbnail* is the desired image style.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution that doesn't require a relationship:

- Add your image field to your view
- Set these properties:

  - Formatter: Image
  - Image style: None (original image)
  - Link image to: File

This gives you an output like this:
    `<a href="http://domain/path/to/file.jpg" ...`

- Under Rewrite results, check "Override the output of this field with custom text"
- In the text box put this:

  `{% if field_image|trim is not empty%}
  {{ field_image|split('"')[1] }}
  {% endif %}`

This splits the string on the `"` character and the index of 1 is your url in the href. It is kinda hacky but this actually gave me what I wanted. Going the relationship route I could only ever get a link with `public:/path/to/file.jpg` not the absolute URL

Comment: I just tried the relationship way and it works. I also got the full url to the image which is good enough for me. I did this: {{ file_url(fields.uri.content|striptags|trim) }} in my fields template.